# Variable is not taking more than one value when deleting multiple rows using checkbox

Tags: php, ajax

1 problem: Variable chk in database is not talking more than one value
2 problem:delete variable is not getting the proper value i.e patient id
I want to delete multiple rows using checkbox
database code:

```
function delete()
{
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rishita_db");
$sql="select * from 14_patientdetails";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>


    <center>
    <h1><u>Patient Details</u></h1>
    <table border="1" style="font-family:Georgia;color:#800000;font-style:bold;">
    <tr style="font-family:Georgia;color:green;font-style:bold;">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Patient ID</th>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone No.</th>
        <th>Medicare</th>
        <th>Doctor Associated</th>
     </tr>
     <form method="post" action="delete.php">
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $r=$row['patientId'];       
?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id="checkbox[]" value=<?php echo $r; ?>></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['patientId']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['patientName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DOB']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Medicare']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Doctor']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
    </table>           
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="del" type="button" onClick='myFunction()' id="del" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <span id="msg"></span>
            </form>

        <script language="javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
        else
            {
                xmlhttp=new Activexobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","delete.php",true)
        var chk=document.getElementById("checkbox[]").value;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("chk="+chk);   }
</script>
<?php

}
```

Server Side:

```
$chk=$_POST['chk'];
   echo "Enter".$chk;
    $chkcount = count($chk);
    echo"<br>count:".$chkcount;
    $del=$chk;
    echo 'del:'.$del;     
   for($i=0;$i<$chkcount;$i++)
    {
        $delete=$del[$i];
        echo "delete: ".$delete;
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rishita_db");
        $sql1 = "DELETE FROM 14_patientdetails WHERE patientId='$delete'";
        $q = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    }
    if($q)
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else{echo 'Fail';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will only ever get the first item using `document.getElementById("checkbox[]")`

I would suggest adding a container and finding the value of all selected elements within it rather, or possibly searching for the name instead

```
<script language="javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else
      {
        xmlhttp=new Activexobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
              document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","delete.php",true)
    var chk=document.getElementsByName("checkbox[]");

    // buffer values into array
    var qAry = [];
    for (var x in chk) {
        if (chk[x].checked) {
            qAry.push('chk[]='+chk[x].value);
        }
    }
    // merge
    qString = qAry.join('&');


    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(qString);   }
</script>
```

I've got it running in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caliburn82/9od15fp5/) for you as well (without the ajax requests unfortunately)

Comment: Sorry, yes it was bugged. I've edited it now for you.. hope it helps

Comment: I implemented this code,when I tried to echo var qString returns empty string :/